# Can I create a tag in a Java class

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play `1.x` i could create a `tag` in Java by extending the `play.templates.FastTags` class.

Is it possible in Play 2.x to create a tag in a Java class or only in a scala.html file ?

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.0 `views` (`templates`) are just Scala functions, so you can easily use some controller's method as a tag:

```
<div>
    @YourController.yourMethod("your param value")
</div>
```

[@see similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11234495/1066240)

Comment: i do not have (i can't have) a controller

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is only possible in scala.html files.

To see how to do it, take a look at the [Play doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaTemplateUseCases).